# Firebase Hosting Polymer ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-hosting

## AskFirebase

The app works well on the localHost but when deployed to firebase , i got the favicon and the tab name with blank screen.

Error on console :
GET https://graphite-proton-861.firebaseapp.com/service-worker.js net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

I followed
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/deploy

Answer (score 0):

Whats in your firebase.json? You will need to supply the correct header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" (research CORS). This is what I use in a project which can be called from any domain:

```
{
  "firebase": "fiery-torch-XXXX-yourref",
  "headers": [ {
    "source" : "**",
    "headers" : [ {
      "key" : "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "value" : "*"
    } ]
  } ],
  "public": ".",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I got no errors any more but it shows a blank page!

Comment: I had a quick look and your file /src/hoverboard-app is 301? Are you not intending to serve eg /dist/ ? Your firebase json should indicate which dirctory to serve for hosting eg 
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist"
  }
}

Comment: my public directory is "build/bundled"

Comment: But you (your script...) are making a request for 'hoverboard-app' from /src/? Sorry, dont know more than that, but I would look at this first:  Request URL:https://graphite-proton-861.firebaseapp.com/src/hoverboard-app.html in your frontend: <link rel="import" href="/src/hoverboard-app.html" async="">